# Rendering random curves with loops between 2 points

Tags: actionscript-3

I need an ActionScript 3 library that renders randomized splines with a set amount of loops in the spline, and while I'm Googling, I was hoping someone could recommend some library that I could perhaps download for this purpose.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think there would be a tailor made  library available for this. You will have to generate random cubic splines (how do you make sure there is a loop in it?) and convert them into quad splines (as the AS `Graphics::curveTo` method draws only quad curves). Waiting to see if there is such a curve library available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at [Degrafa](http://www.degrafa.org/docs/com/degrafa/geometry/splines/package-detail.html), plenty of splines there. They were implemented by [Jim Armstrong](http://algorithmist.wordpress.com/2008/12/02/degrafa-introduction-to-splines-part-i/), it's worth checking out his site. Loads of explanations for Cardinal Splines, Catmull-Rom Splines, Hermite Curves, etc.

Depends what exactly you're trying to achieve. I'd say have look on Wikipedia at different types of curves, find the one that best suits your needs, then [google](http://code.google.com/p/bezier/).

HTH